# div css multiple class selectors and css class assignment

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to set a background image to a `div`, but somehow I have problems to understand the selection of the css class attribute.

The identifier which I want to use is the first `div` (id="ext-element-283") **mainmenuitem** and **x-treelist-row-over** and the lower div **(id="ext-element-281") menu-po-trek.**

How do I have to define the css class selector to apply the css to the specific div. (id="ext-element-281)"

```css
.mainmenuitem .x-treelist-row-over .menu-po-trek {
 height: 64px;
 vertical-align: middle !important;
 background-size: 44px 33px;
 background-image: url("/icons/pltx2/po.png") !important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-treelist-row mainmenuitem x-treelist-row-over" id="ext-element-283">
 <div class="x-treelist-item-wrap" id="ext-element-258" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <div class="x-treelist-item-icon menu-po-trek" id="ext-element-281"></div>
  <div class="x-treelist-item-text" id="ext-element-280">Po</div>
  <div class="x-treelist-item-expander"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the answer is : "read more about how CSS selector works" and then you will get your answer

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm not fully understanding your question, if you want to set a background image to a specific div do this:

```
#ext-element-283 {
    height: 64px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    background-size: 44px 33px;
    background-image: url("/icons/pltx2/po.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

If you want to apply the css to 2 divs then do this:

```
#ext-element-283,
#ext-element-281 {
   height: 64px;
   vertical-align: middle !important;
   background-size: 44px 33px;
   background-image: url("/icons/pltx2/po.png") !important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the classes use the dot "`.`" (e.g. `.mainmenuitem`) while to select the IDs use the hash "`#`" (e.g. `#ext-element-283`). Try with this:

```css
#ext-element-283 {
 height: 250px;
 background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/500x250/E8117F/AAAAAA");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}

#ext-element-281 {
 height: 150px;
 background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/ffffff/000000");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-treelist-row mainmenuitem x-treelist-row-over" id="ext-element-283">
 <div class="x-treelist-item-wrap" id="ext-element-258" style="margin-left: 0px;">
  <div class="x-treelist-item-icon menu-po-trek" id="ext-element-281"></div>
  <div class="x-treelist-item-text" id="ext-element-280">Po</div>
  <div class="x-treelist-item-expander"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding the last sentence of your question, that will be

```
#ext-element-281.x-treelist-item-icon.menu-po-trek { ... }
```

i.e. all classes and the ID written in *one* string, without spaces, with leading dots for the classes and a leading `#` for the ID

Actually the ID alone should be enough, since IDs are unique, but if you need a selector with higher specifity to overwrite another rule, that's the way to go